# Flask send file without storing on server

Tags: python, flask

I want the user to be able to download a txt file that contains results of a sql query. I've seen answers speaking about using `send_file` or `Response` but all of those answers seem to require that I have the file stored?

Currently I have:

```
@RateRevisionEndorsements_blueprint.route('/_getEndorsements', methods = ['GET'])
def get_endorsements():
    guid = request.args.get('guid')


    client = Client()

    # Save query results    
    result = client.getEndorsementFile(bookGuid = guid)


    with open('tesult.txt', 'w') as r:
        for i in result:
            r.write(i)

    return send_file("result.txt", as_attachment=True)
```

The button to generate this route works and I have no issue receiving the query results (currently stored as a list but I can make it whatever works best), but I receive the error  `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C"\\..\\app\\result.txt'`
Which makes me think that I need it to have stored somewhere on the server to pull from.

Answer (score 4):

Just send the data as a [streaming response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/streaming/). Make sure to set the proper mime type so that the browser will initiate a download.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly send_file sent files that are stored.
Sent it with the

```
Respone(file,mimetype=“txt/plain”)
```